# asp.net can not find seed data during docker publish

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile

Repository.Data.RepositoryContextSeed[0]
e-commerece-app-1      |       Could not find a part of the path '/Repository/Data/SeedData/brands.json'.
e-commerece-app-1      | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
e-commerece-app-1      |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.

Repository.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
.......
<ItemGroup> 
  <Content Include="Data\SeedData\**"> 
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </Content>
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
namespace Repository.Data
{
    public class RepositoryContextSeed
    {
        public static async Task
        SeedAsync(RepositoryContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!context.ProductBrands.Any())
                {
                    var brandsData =
                        File
                            .ReadAllText("../Repository/Data/SeedData/brands.json");
                    var brands =
                        JsonConvert
                            .DeserializeObject<List<ProductBrand>>(brandsData);

                    await context.ProductBrands.AddRangeAsync(brands);
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RepositoryContextSeed>();
                logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

docker file

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build-env


WORKDIR /e-commerece
COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY ./*/*.csproj ./
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ./${file%.*}/ && mv $file ./${file%.*}/; done
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the SeedData files to the published directory
COPY ./Repository/Data/SeedData /e-commerece/publish/Repository/Data/SeedData
COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish ./API/API.csproj -c Release -o /publish/

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as runtime
WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=build-env /publish .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

When i run dotnet run everthing is fine and i can seed the data.
But i cant seed the data inside docker

Comment: I had a similar issue, and the only thing that worked for me was putting the SeedData folder inside the wwwroot. I don't know if thats a bad practice, but im still a noob with containers and thats all i could manage to make it work.